# Using chosen.js, how would I add images to the dropdown items?

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Using chosen.js, how would I add images to the dropdown items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By setting a `background-image` on chosen's list items:

```css
.chzn-results li {
    background: url('path/to/img.png') no-repeat 3px center;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
```

Adjust the pixel count accordingly.

Comment: Solution: CSS rule should be `background` not `background-image`.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Joseph (I can't add comment to his answer), the class has changed since an unknown version:
Here's the correct css in v1.0.0:

```
li.active-result {
    background: url('path/to/img.png') no-repeat 3px center;
    text-indent:2em;
}
```

Thx Joseph!