# jQuery chosen: add a background-image?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

How would I add a background image to a list element in a jQuery Chosen select dropdown?

There is [already a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271283/using-chosen-js-how-would-i-add-images-to-the-dropdown-items), but I can't get the accepted answer to work.

My code:

```
.chzn-results li {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/20/20') no-repeat 3px center;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

JSFiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RVH8D/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/RVH8D/6/

CSS

```
.chzn-results li {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/20/20') no-repeat 3px center;

}
li.active-result { 
    padding-left: 12px;    
}
.chzn-results, .chzn-single { 
    font-family: Arial;    
}
.chzn-container .chzn-results li{padding-left: 25px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used to this `background` than used `all properties`

```
.chzn-results li {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/20/20') no-repeat 3px center;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
```

## ==========

if you are using

```
background-image:
```

Than used to this way

```
.chzn-results li{
background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/20/20');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:3px center;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RVH8D/5/)**